# Passed the function in AddEventListener

Tags: javascript

When I passed my function in `addEventListener()` method, it don't work right. Event don't register, and my function don't call.

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/alg0re/Uduh4/)

```
 <div id="box-wrap">
        <ul id="colorize">
        </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function colorize(){
var ul = document.getElementById('colorize');

for(var i = 0; i < 36; i++){
    ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
}

function randomColor(li){
    li.style.background= "#"+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);


}
var liElements = ul.children;
for (i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++){
 liElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover',randomColor(liElements[i]),false);
    }

}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: `addEventListener('mouseover',randomColor(liElements[i]),false)` **calls** `randomColor` and passes its return value into `addEventListener`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

Comment: Your random colour generator is a tad off: it may yield something like `#34b9d`, perhaps use `#"+('000000'+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)).slice(-6)`or, sticking with your code: `('000' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6)` around your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead of

```
liElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover',randomColor(liElements[i]),false);
```

using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (be ware that this does only work in modern browsers), but the link has a fall back implementation for it)

```
liElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover',randomColor.bind(this, liElements[i]),false);
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd argument to `addEventListener` must be a function, you're giving it `undefined` (the output of `randomColor(..)`

Call it like this:

```
liElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    randomColor(liElements[i]);
} ,false);
```

And now you'll run into a closure problem (`i` has the wrong value), fix like so:

```
(function (bound_i) {
    liElements[bound_i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        randomColor(liElements[bound_i]);
    } ,false);
} (i)); // <-- immediate invocation (IIFE)
```

Comment: Or even better, with a forEach which already introduces a closure :)

Comment: And if not using `forEach`, at least make the factory function something named and outside the loop. There's no need to create a new *factory* function on every loop iteration, just a new event handler function. It's also best practice to use a **different** name for the argument, for clarity.

Comment: Or better still: _delegate_ the event, instead of binding all those individual listeners...

Comment: @TJCrowder I agree that it improves performance (marginally) but it doesn't improve readability. You're welcome to write your own answer. @Elias you need to bind `i` somehow, how would you do it?

Comment: Here is [**what I'd do**](http://jsfiddle.net/HCK8b/) in a similar solution to this.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Check my answer and linked fiddle, there's no need for a closure to get around the loop-issue: there's only 1 event listener. If the target of the mouseover is a `li`, then change its colour, it doesn't matter which `li` it is